# Use a generic type to pass a specific class

Tags: java, json

I'm very new to programming language. My question might not even make sense. My environment is using java and trying to implement both ios and android apps in the same automation testing framework.
So, the idea is that any test script should be able to run on both the apps. Ex: one signin test script should be run for both ios and android.
I've decided to use interface and class implementation approach. The problem I'm facing is with test data. My company doesn't want to use excel. They want to use json for test data.

Here's my problem, look at the following line of code:

```
ValidBuy goodBuy = JsonFileReader.loadDaTa(TestBase.DATA_PATH, "good-buy.json", ValidBuy.class);
```

As you can see I have a class "ValidBuy" that has all the getters for a particular json file. I have another class "JsonFileReader" which takes the json filePath, fileName, and a class as an input and returns the data for that class name that I passed in. For this example I've passed ValidBuy.class

So, when I run a positive test, I'm passing "goodBuy" variable which is of type "ValidBuy". The problem starts here.
The test case is now specified with the data from goodBuy because it's type is "ValidBuy" and I'm passing goodBuy as a parameter.

Look at one of my extracted methods:

```
private void enterBuyInfo(ValidBuy goodBuy) {
    itemPage = nativeApp.getItemPage(goodBuy);
    itemPage.setItemName(goodBuy.getItemName());
    itemPage.setItemSize(goodBuy.getItemSize());
    itemPage.setItemDigitSSN(goodBuy.getSsn());
    itemPage.clickContinue();
}
```

You can see those getters I'm using are coming from ValidBuy class.
If I run this test with the data for a badBuy:

```
InvalidBuy badBuy = JsonFileReader.loadDaTa(TestBase.DATA_PATH, "bad-buy.json", InvalidBuy.class);
```

It fails because now I have to change "ValidBuy" class with "InvalidBuy" class.  Since, changing the parameter in the extracted method in every run is not possible, how can I make it more generic?

I want something like this:

```
TestData data = JsonFileReader.loadDaTa(RESOURCES_PATH, "good-client.json", InvalidBuy.class);
```

Here, TestData is generic. It could either be a class or interface (I don't know if that's possible) and the return type will be specified by whichever class I pass into the loadData() method. In this case InvalidBuy.class

```
The extracted method should look like this:

private void enterBuyInfo(TestData data) {
    itemPage = nativeApp.getItemPage(data);
    itemPage.setItemName(data.getItemName());
    itemPage.setItemSize(data.getItemSize());
    itemPage.setItemDigitSSN(data.getSsn());
    itemPage.clickContinue();
}
```

If I can do this, I can use those extracted methods to create more tests.

I know I wrote a lot. I've only tried to make it as clear as possible. If it doesn't make any sense, just disregard it.

Any suggestions, ideas, code samples will be highly appreciated.

Comment: TL; I did not read all of it. The definition of `itemPage` is missing. From what I see can you have `TestData` and `ValidBuy` implement the same `Info` interface and have `enterBuyInfo(Info info)` ? `Info` should define the three common methods `getItemName()` , `getItemSize()` and  `getSsn()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let me see if I understand your question. I think you are saying that `loadData` may return a value of type `ValidBuy` or `InvalidBuy` and you want to pass into it the class that you want returned. You then want to know how to use an interface that might represent either of these classes in your test methods so you can test various return values (both valid and invalid). You use the term "generic" in your question but I'm guessing you don't mean to use it in the specific way it's used in Java.

If I've understood your question correctly, then here's an answer:

Passing the class you wish to have returned into a method is an unusual usage and almost certainly not ideal. Better OOD would be to extract the common methods for all objects returned from `loadData` into an interface.

So:

```
interface Buy {
    String getItemName();
    boolean isValid();
}

class ValidBuy implements Buy {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}

class InvalidBuy implements Buy {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return false;
    }
    ...
}

class JsonFileReader {
    Buy loadData(Path path) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then your tests can look like:

```
@Test
void testValidBuy() {
    assertTrue(reader.loadData(validPath).isvalid());
}

@Test
void testInvalidBuy() {
    assertFalse(reader.loadData(invalidPath).isValid());
}
```

I realise I've simplified it a bit but hopefully you get the idea.